# RestException [Error]: Too many requests status: 429, code: 20429,

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

helper function
below is my helper function which do two things.
1.generateotp function will send otp to mobile from req.body(here i pass two parametr mobile number and channel. channel is mode of sending otp means sms or otp here it is sms)
2.secon function will verify  the otp which user recived. here also we take 2 parameter mobile number and otp

```
var db = require('../config/connection');
const config=  require('../config/config');
const collection = require('../config/connection');
const client = require("twilio")(config.accountSID,config.authToken)
module.exports={ 
     generateOtp:(userNumber,channel) => {
        client
        .verify
        .services(config.serviceID)
        .verifications
        .create({
          to:`+91${userNumber}`,
          channel:channel
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            // return callback(null, 'success');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
     },
     
     verifyOtp:(userNumber,userOtp) => {
         client
         .verify
         .services(config.serviceID)
         .verificationChecks
         .create({
            to:`+91$${userNumber}`,
            code:userOtp

         })
         .then((data) => {
             console.log(data);
         })
         .catch((error) => {
             console.llog(error);
         })
     }
}
```

Route

```
/Generate Otp
 router.post('/signup',(req,res) => { 
   const {userNumber, channel} = req.body;
    userhelper.generateOtp(userNumber,channel)
    return res.redirect('/verify');
 });
 //Verify Otp
 router.post('/verify',(req,res) => {
   const {userNumber,userOtp} = req.body;
   console.log(req.body);
  // userhelper.verifyOtp(userNumber,userOtp)
 })
```

I am using twilio verify api for mobile number verification the above code worked perfectly till yesterday now when is test code i am getting an error.

```
RestException [Error]: Too many requests
    at success (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\twilio\lib\base\Version.js:135:15)
    at Promise_then_fulfilled (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\q\q.js:766:44)
    at Promise_done_fulfilled (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\q\q.js:835:31)
    at Fulfilled_dispatch [as dispatch] (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\q\q.js:1229:9)
    at Pending_become_eachMessage_task (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\q\q.js:1369:30)
    at RawTask.call (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\asap\asap.js:40:19)
    at flush (C:\Users\Alfas Ahmed\Desktop\whatsapp-ecom\node_modules\asap\raw.js:50:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  status: 429,
  code: 20429,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20429',
  details: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How to test Twilio Verify without getting rate limited
https://www.twilio.com/blog/test-verify-no-rate-limits

Answer (score 1):

Above what happened is, in development time I just tested many time with same mobile number. Twilio just blocked service. So I just created new Service id , now the code working perfectly fine.