# Twilio Verify API response Error 20429 "Too Many Requests" Block 24 hours

Tags: twilio, http-status-code-429

Problem:  Getting exception "HTTP 429 error: Unable to create record: Too many requests"using the verify api with php.  Testing, but not exceeding the specified limits (5x within 10 min), so there must be something else.  Locks me out for a full 24 hours, which is very inconvenient.  So it is not just a single verification.  If I knew what to NOT do, or how to reset that would be great.

The verification testing dashboard is not an option for me (don't use node/ npm), and I'm not sure it would help, since this doesn't seem to be about a single verification.

Question: Is there some way to manage this from my Twilio account? The error object does not include useful information (like how many tries, or expiration).  It's not 60203, but 20429.

`[content:protected] => {"code": 20429, "message": "Too many requests", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20429", "status": 429}`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are some other rate restrictions, not just 5 times within 10 minutes, you can read about them here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/rate-limits-and-timeouts#status-check-rate-limits.

Another person was [having the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623721/restexception-error-too-many-requests-status-429-code-20429) and found that [creating a new service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65624841/28376) to work with meant that they could continue their work.

Comment: Thank you for that link!  As far as I know I have not come close to any of the limits, but I appreciate the link to the additional info, I had not seen that page.  Twilio customer service says that it's because of being a test account, and just recommended that I upgrade to a full account if I want to keep testing errors.  My account did get released, but if it happens again I will try a different service as suggested. Meanwhile I will just space my error tests further apart if I can.

Comment: Hey @philnash why would Twilio place such tight restrictions? It seems ridiculous because our platform certainly processes 250 requests per day and this is now blocking our entire system.